# ASP.NET MVC: avoid tight coupling when binding form POST to parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelbinders, defaultmodelbinder

Let's say I have an interface like:

```
interface IThing {
   int Id { get; set; }
   string Title { get; set; }
}
```

And in ASP.NET MVC I have a form that posts to a controller action like this:

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
 public ActionResult NewThing([Bind(Exclude = "Id")] SimpleThing thing) {

    // code to validate and persist the thing can go here            
 }
```

Where *SimpleThing* is a concrete class that just barely implements *IThing*.

However, I would like all my methods to deal with the interface.  I have a data assembly that uses NHiberate and its own *IThing* implementation (let's call it *RealThing*).  I can't pass the SimpleThing to it because it will complain about an "unknown entity".

Does anyone have any ideas about a cleaner way to do this?  I was thinking about something along the lines of using a factory class.  But how would I get the MVC form binder to use it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some good suggestions here and I actually came up with a solution that works.  However, I ended up with something altogether.  I just created models specific for the form data I was posting and used the default model binder.

Much simpler and it allows me to capture data that isn't part of my domain model (ie. like a "comments" field).

Comment: Hi user10789, have you put this swift bounty?

Answer (score 4):

You can use custom [model binders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410405.aspx). However article on msdn is totally useless. So better to employ search and find something better. There are planaty of articles available.

Answer (score 3):

I came up with two approaches to this.

The first was to add code to my NHibernate Repository class to translate the simple POCO type used by the MVC controller (*SimpleThing*) to the type of entity that NHibernate wanted (*RealThing*):

```
/// <summary>
/// A NHibernate generic repository.  Provides base of common 
/// methods to retrieve and update data.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The base type to expose 
/// repository methods for.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="K">The concrete type used by NHibernate</typeparam>
public class NHRepositoryBase<T, K> 
    : IRepository<T>
    where T : class
    where K : T, new()
{
    // repository methods ...

    /// <summary>
    /// Return T item as a type of K, converting it if necessary
    /// </summary>        
    protected static K GetKnownEntity(T item) {
        if (typeof(T) != typeof(K)) {
            K knownEntity = new K();

            foreach (var prop in typeof(T).GetProperties()) { 
                object value = prop.GetValue(item, null);
                prop.SetValue(knownEntity, value, null);
            }

            return knownEntity;
        } else {

            return (K)item;
        }            
    }
```

So, any method in the repository can call GetKnownEntity(T item) and it will copy the properties of the item you pass in to the type that NHibernate wants.  Obviously this felt a bit clunky, so I looked in to custom model binders.

---

In the second approach, I created a custom model binder like this:

```
public class FactoryModelBinder<T> 
    : DefaultModelBinder 
    where T : new() 
{

    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, 
                                          ModelBindingContext bindingContext, 
                                          Type modelType) {

        return new T();                       
    }

}
```

Then I registered that in Global.asax.cs with:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(IThing), 
            new FactoryModelBinder<RealThing>());
```

And it works fine with a Controller Action that looks like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult NewThing([Bind(Exclude = "Id")] IThing thing) {
    // code to process the thing goes here
}
```

---

I like the second approach, but most of my dependency injection stuff is in the Controller class.  I don't like to have to add all these ModelBinder mappings in Global.asax.cs.

Comment: I think second solution its very easy automate (either with code generation or with reflection).

Answer (score 0):

This is not dirrect unswer to your question.

We use slightly different approach to deal with same problem you have. Our Controllers accepts DTOs that match persistent entity field by field. Then we user [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) to create persisten entities that will go to the database. This eliminates unnessesery interfaces and locks down public facing API (means that renaming persistance object's field will not break our client code).