# Database web app with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/movie-database/create-a-movie-database-application-in-15-minutes-with-asp-net-mvc-cs) tutorial on how to create a simple database web application with ASP.NET MVC. I am having a problem with the 2nd `Create` controller method in the home controller (in [Listing 4](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/movie-database/create-a-movie-database-application-in-15-minutes-with-asp-net-mvc-cs#creating-new-database-records)). Specifically, the error - when the web app is built - is with the `AddToMovieSet` method that actually saves the entries to the database.

It is worth noting that I am using VS 2016, whereas the tutorial uses a much older version (2008); this might be the reason to the problem. But, nevertheless, what is the code for this `Create` controller method?

This is the code in the `Create` action method in the home controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(Movie movieToCreate)
{
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(); 

    _db.AddToMovieSet(movieToCreate);
    _db.SaveChanges(); 

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to create a new Movie and save it to the database? What exactly are you trying to accomplish? I'm not understanding what exactly the problem you are having.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to add a movie and save it to the database.

Comment: Also, that appears to be a MVC1 tutorial. You'll probably have a better experience with a newer one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application. MVC4 is still much like MVC5. And the Entity Framework version changes are also significant.

Comment: @Jasen, the thing is, as a beginner, I found MVC1 much more straight forward than MVC4. Is there a way to adapt the latter to the former in this instance?

Comment: This one is closer to the movie theme https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/ and also newer. The major difficulty with the MVC1 tutorial is the EF changes.

Comment: No matter the version.. your question is very unclear.  What **exactly** is the problem you're experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have proper view created for this action method. Else create view or return view explicitly with name.

Comment: I have created a view for this action method. The problem is with the code within the "Create" action method

Comment: Can you please share the code. So we can identify the problem.

Comment: This this an old example please follow something else. Your question is quite similar to this - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080925/asp-net-mvc-avoid-tight-coupling-when-binding-form-post-to-parameter